# CClientDC and DC not Drawing on ChtmlEditCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, cdc

Hi all I am working with a CHtmlEditCtrl in MFC. I want to draw some random rectangles and lines inside a function handling right click event.

The ChtmlEditCtrl control is created from static using this snippet:

```
bool CHtmlEditCtrlEx::CreateFromStatic( UINT nID, CWnd* pParent ) {
    CStatic wndStatic;
    if ( !wndStatic.SubclassDlgItem(nID, pParent)) {
        return false;
    }
    CRect rc;
    wndStatic.GetWindowRect( &rc );
    pParent->ScreenToClient( &rc );
    if (Create( 0, (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE), rc, pParent, nID, 0 )) {
        ...
}
```

Then I override the CWnd::pretranslate() function as thus:

```
  CClientDC dcc(this);
    switch (pMsg->message) {

        case WM_RBUTTONUP:  // Right-click
            // Just some dummy values
            DrawSquigly(dcc, 600, 240, 20);
            break;

    }
```

the DrawSquigly() function is defined as thus:

```
void CHtmlEditCtrlEx::DrawSquigly(CDC &dcc, int iLeftX, int iWidth, int iY)
{
    CAMTrace trace;
    trace.Trace("Drawing Squiggly");
    //dcc.TextOut(10, 10, CString(_T("I used a client DC!")));

    CPen * oldPen;
    CBrush * oldBrush;
    oldPen = (CPen *) dc.SelectStockObject(WHITE_PEN);
    dcc.MoveTo(5,10);
    dcc.LineTo(80, 10);
    dcc.SelectObject(oldPen);

    //GDI 002_2: Create custom pen with different Line thickness.
    CPen thick_pen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0,255,0));
    oldPen = dc.SelectObject(&thick_pen);
    dcc.MoveTo(5, 20);
    dcc.LineTo(80,20);
    dcc.SelectObject(oldPen);

    //GDI 002_3: Create a Rectangle now
    dcc.Draw3dRect(5,30,80,70, RGB(25,25,255), RGB(120,120,120));

    //GDI 002_4: Create a Brush that we can use for filling the 
    // closed surfaces
    CBrush brush(RGB(255,0,255));
    oldBrush = dc.SelectObject(&brush);
    dcc.Rectangle(5,110,80,140);
    dcc.SelectObject(oldBrush);

    //GDI 002_5: Hatch Brush is useful to apply a pattern in stead 
    //of solid fill color
    CBrush* hatBrush = new CBrush();
    hatBrush->CreateHatchBrush(HS_CROSS, RGB(255,0,255));
    oldBrush = dc.SelectObject(hatBrush);
    dcc.FillRect(new CRect(5,160,80,190), hatBrush);
    dcc.SelectObject(oldBrush);
}
```

but no drawing happens when I right click. I think I am missing something especially because I am new to MFC.

I have added a trace to the top of the event handler to be sure that the function is getting called and it is.

Can anyone please point me the right direction?

Comment: Are you calling this from an override of `CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage()`? That isn't the right place to handle events.

Comment: What's the purpose of dcc when the function has a dc parameter?

Comment: Yes I am calling the override of CWnd::PreTranslateMessage, I handled the events here because there are going to be several client areas on the view where the CHtmlEditCtrl is included. to test that the function gets call, I added a trace to the top, which traces out, but not not drawing.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 device context in your code: one you pass as parameter in the call (we don't know where it comes from) and the other created locally in the drawing function.

Normally, when the systems gives you a DC it expects you draw something in it, not that you draw into something else.

If the window you are working on is layered, the system gives you a memory context you draw in that is - upon clearing - blit-ted onto the window itself with some window manager effect.

My suspect is that -by allocating a second dc- your drawing are ovewritten when the first one (you left blank) is cleared upon returning from the message handler.

Comment: I have put a 5 seconds delay after the handler is called to verify your assumption:   DrawSquigly(dc, 600, 240, 20);
  Sleep(5000); but still cannot see any drawing.

Comment: The refresh of the screen does not necessarily happen synchronously. If you put the process asleep synchronously may be you pause before the refresh.

Comment: I have edited the question above, what would your recommendation be in this case?

Comment: where did you get the dc you pass when calling  DrawSquigly(dc, 600, 240, 20) ??

Comment: just on top of the message swtich statement in the CWnd::pretranslate function, but am not even using it, I tried to get another from the event handler to test that it works.

Comment: I have edited the question to get rid of the local DC.